# READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE are the only valid transaction levels

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I'm experimenting with transaction management in spring boot and I got this error:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: READ_COMMITTED et SERIALIZABLE sont les seuls niveaux de transaction valides] with root cause
```

java.sql.SQLException: READ_COMMITTED et SERIALIZABLE sont les seuls niveaux de transaction
valides

Translation:

```
READ_COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE are the only valid transaction levels
```

Here are the steps to reproduce:

```
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    DefaultTransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    definition.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ);
    definition.setTimeout(3);
    TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(definition);
    try {
        Payment payment = new Payment();
        payment.setReferenceNumber("Ref-1");
        payment.setState(Payment.State.SUCCESSFUL);
        paymentJpaRepository.save(payment);
        transactionManager.commit(status);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        transactionManager.rollback(status);
    }
```

Why can't I use repeatable read ? Also I didn't find any example mixing spring data repositories with PlatformTransactionManager, is this even legal ?
(I didn't create any specific bean for PlatformTransactionManager and EntityManager, it's all default)

I tried with READ_COMMITED and it works correctly, I just want to understand why.

Jdbc url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@myHost:myPort/mySid
Oracle version: 11g

Comment: Which DB engine are you using? The explanation is likely: "Because the DB engine and/or JDBC driver doesn't let you", hence, that's crucial info. Edit your question and add this information; include the JDBC URL (wipe out any username or passwords in it if you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation from Oracle themselves:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#CNCPT1317

In 11g with the thin driver, they only support

- Read committed (the default)
- Serializable
- Read-only